# org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep : Encountered an error executing the step

Tags: java, spring, batch-file, spring-batch, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring chunk batch with my customizes `JPAPagingItemReder`. The issue I'm encountering now is that whenever my reader moves to second page for reading the results from query, it get following exception.

```
org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter : DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-270, SQLSTATE=42997, SQLERRMC=63, DRIVER=3.61.65
2016-05-26 14:52:17,842 ERROR [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-4][osamam:26719] org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter : DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-270;42997;63, DRIVER=3.61.65
2016-05-26 14:52:17,842 ERROR [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-4][osamam:26719] org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter : DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-270;42997;63, DRIVER=3.61.65
2016-05-26 14:52:18,114 ERROR [jobLauncherTaskExecutor-4][osamam:26719] org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep : Encountered an error executing the step
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1215)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1148)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:255)
    at com.innovation.api.postdata.batch.JpaPagingItemReader.doReadPage(JpaPagingItemReader.java:53)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractPagingItemReader.doRead(AbstractPagingItemReader.java:107)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor307.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:686)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    at com.innovation.api.postdata.batch.JpaPagingItemReader$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$86746fac.doRead(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:85)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:90)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:108)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:367)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:143)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:103)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:68)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:386)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:264)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:76)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:367)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:143)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:250)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:281)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2536)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:246)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-270, SQLSTATE=42997, SQLERRMC=63, DRIVER=3.61.65
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:676)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:127)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gn.c(gn.java:2554)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gn.d(gn.java:2542)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gn.a(gn.java:2034)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hn.a(hn.java:6500)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.g(cb.java:140)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.a(cb.java:40)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.q.a(q.java:32)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.rb.i(rb.java:135)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gn.gb(gn.java:2005)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hn.qc(hn.java:3053)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hn.b(hn.java:3838)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hn.dc(hn.java:683)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hn.executeQuery(hn.java:657)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
    ... 51 more
```

Below is the code of my customized `JPAPagingItemReader`s `doReadPage()` method.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected void doReadPage ()
{
    // Flush we already have in entity manager
    getEntityManager ().flush ();

    // clear the entity manager: To read and detach
    getEntityManager ().clear ();

    int firstResult = getPage () * getPageSize ();

    Query query = createQuery ().setFirstResult (firstResult).setMaxResults (getPageSize ());

    if (parameterValues != null)
    {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> me : parameterValues.entrySet ())
        {
            query.setParameter (me.getKey (), me.getValue ());
        }
    }

    if (results == null)
    {
        results = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<T> ();
    }
    else
    {
        results.clear ();
    }

    results.addAll (query.getResultList ());
}
```

Comment: Why do you need this? What does this add that the default doesn't do?

Comment: I'll be adding my customized things later, like commit interval etc. but as i was failing at the initial step that's why i'm asking question.
For the first page my reader works fine, but when it reads query for the second time(second page). It is throwing exception.

Comment: Spring Batch already provides that... Looks like you are trying to work around the framework instead of working with the framework. This is still more or less the default then use the default instead of reimplementing the same. Just call super. If you want to add stuff add it before/after calling the `super`.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum ,, I tried it , but I am still facing the same issue. I have used Spring Batch **JPAPagingItemReader** , but it is failing at the same step. `results.addAll (query.getResultList ());` is throwing exception when is it getting called for the second page.

Comment: Then there must be something with your query (or a result of our query). Check what the database error s means (you have the error codes so google those).

Comment: SQLCODE=-270, SQLSTATE=42997 means function is not supported, en detail it is used for statements which try to change database structure (table structure, query names, etc.), please add db2 jdbc tracing to your connection and check the sql statement which leads to this problem

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks :)

Comment: @M.Deinum ...... I have sorted out the problem. It was due to CLOB data present in my query result. When I removed that CLOB result from my query result. It worked properly fine.
Thanks :)